# How to trigger websocket send from another function in Node?

Tags: node.js, websocket

It's been a while since I've worked with Node and Websockets. Basically how do I get socket.send() to work from another function is what I'm stuck on.

```
const server = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

server.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('message', message => {
    console.log(`received from a client: ${message}`);
  });
  socket.send('yo world!');
});

function onMessageHandler (target, context, msg, self) {
    client.say(target, response);
    server.socket.send(response);
    console.log(response);
  }
}
```

How do I get my onMessageHandler to trigger a socket send, this is fail... server.socket.send(response);

Comment: May be store the Socket in a global variable?

Comment: @Vishal-Lia it already is I think? const server = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

Comment: Can't you pass the `socket` as an argument to the `onMessageHandler`? Storing a socket as a global variable is not a good idea because with each new connection there is a new socket object created so that global variable would be overridden with each connection. @Serhiy that `const server = ...` is not a socket object, it's a WS server object ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your question i think there is a lack of understanding on how Websockets work. I am assuming you're using https://github.com/websockets/ws

There are two things. First is the WebSocketerver which you've named as `server` and then an Individual Socket which you've named as `socket`

Now the thing to understand is socket is not accessible outside `server.on() callback` The reason for this is there could be 1000 of sockets connected at a given instance and there would be no way to uniquely identify a particular socket you want to send message to.

So ask yourself the question that your application wants to send message to an individual socket to send to everyone who is connected to your server (basically broadcast)

**If you want to send to an individual, you will have to uniquely identify the user**

```
this._wss = new WebSocket.Server({
            port: ENV_APP_PORT_WS
        });

        this._wss.on("connection", async (ws: AppWebSocket, req: IncomingMessage) => {
            // const ipAddress = req.connection.remoteAddress; // IP Address of User
            logger.info(req);

            const queryParams = url.parse(req.url, true).query;

            let authUser: User;
            try {
                authUser = await this._authenticateWebSocket(queryParams);
            } catch (e) {
                // Terminate connection and return...
            }

            // WS User INIT
            ws.isAlive = true;
            ws.userId = authUser.id;
            ws.uuid = Helpers.generateUUIDV4();

            ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                type: "connected",
                env: ENV
            }));
        });
```

The above code will add a property to each socket object that will enable it to uniquely identify a particular user/socket.

While sending =>

```
    onMessageHandler(targetUserId: number, message: string) {
        const allSockets = <AppWebSocket[]>Array.from(this._wss.clients.values());
        const targetSocket = allSockets.find(w => w.userId === targetUserId);

        targetSocket.send(message);
    }
```

**If You want to send to all connect users, it's quite easy:**
https://github.com/websockets/ws#server-broadcast